# mysql_real_escape_string() in .NET Framework

Tags: php, .net, mysql, sql-server, escaping

i want to find a function in .NET framework to calls SQL-Server's library for escaping really a value for sending to sql server, as [mysql-real-escape-string()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) calls MySQL's library to do in PHP.
please propose a method that i can call it and it return escaped string via one round-trip to database, no need fo executing It's query
Is there it?

Comment: Btw: mysql_real_escape_string does not talk to the database in any way. Also: The proposed solution from @Thomas is fine, just like prepared statements are also the way to go in php

Comment: @edorian - mysql_real_escape_string() actually talks to the database: it's the server the one that gets the job done and it won't work without a DB connection.

Comment: @Alvaro: It requires a connection to determine the character set to use to escape the content.  But no round trip happens.  All the escaping is done on the client side.  Don't believe me?  Break out wireshark and watch the communication betwen PHP and MySQL.  The client does the escaping (which also is the only thing that makes sense)...

Comment: @ircmaxell - I've just tested and you are absolutely right. I misunderstood the `mysql_real_escape_string() calls MySQL's library function mysql_real_escape_string` part in the documentation. It obviously refers to the client library.

Comment: thanks @ircmaxell & @Alvaro for your efforts. i relied it very in my applications. because i misunderstood as @ircmaxell did. now, can i rely it yet(when it is client-side)? or its better to using  "Prepared Statement"(Using Functions: mysqli_stmt_prepare(),mysqli_stmt_bind_param()) instead? (aspect of security-escaping task)

Comment: @ahoo: prepared statements (or more accurately parameterized queries) are the better option all around.  You can rely on client-side escaping only if you set the character set properly and use it properly.  Like any tool it's only as good as how it's used...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why do you want to do that? The correct way to send user input to the database is not to escape it, but to use [query parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.aspx).

```
using(var command = new SqlCommand("insert into MyTable(X, Y) values(@x, @y)", connection))
{
    command.Parameters.Add("@x", textBoxX.Text);
    command.Parameters.Add("@y", textBoxY.Text);
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

This provides better performance, because the query text is always the same so the query execution plan can be cached. This also protects you against SQL injection attacks. And it also allows you to ignore data formatting issues (e.g. how is a DateTime formatted in SQL-Server? How should you represent a number in SQL? and so on)

Comment: yes, i thought about it well. but parameter way has a problem: parameters count is fixed, but i want to dynamically create sql with count of parameters is dependent on user input values.

Comment: @ahoo, the parameter count isn't fixed, nothing prevents you from adding parameters dynamically in a loop... Of course in that case you don't get the performance benefit, but it's still better than hard-coding the values in the SQL query.

Comment: thanks @Thomas, so it is just like "Prepared Statement" in PHP (Using Functions: mysqli_stmt_prepare(),mysqli_stmt_bind_param()). is it right?

Comment: @ahoo, yes, it's roughly the same. BTW, you can explicitly `Prepare()` a command in .NET too if you intend to reuse it multiple times with different parameter values